# How to Force 'WWW' on Google App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

How to force 'WWW' on Google App Engine? For my PHP scripts, I'm using:

```
<?php
if (substr($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 0, 4) != 'www.') {
    header("Location: https://www.{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
}
?>
```

But obviously, this wouldn't work for static files such as `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml`.

e.g. `https://example.com/robots.txt` would not redirect to `https://www.example.com/robots.txt`
e.g. `https://example.com/sitemap.xml` would not redirect to `https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml`

At first, I thought I could resolve the issue by only pointing the subdomain (www.example.com) to Google App Engine, but then I realized the naked domain (example.com) wouldn't be reachable.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you try doing a 301 redirect from `example.com` to `www.example.com` for all requests coming in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a redirect for the naked domain to the WWW subdomain using my DNS provider's service.

The WWW subdomain then maps to the App Engine instance.

You can visit gflip.net as an example.

The drawback of this approach is that the naked domain is never used, but this is not been a problem for me at least - it even works for SSL connections.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What type of DNS record did you use to achieve that?

Comment: It's not a DNS record. It is achieved by forwarding the request for the naked domain.
This forwarding service is a value-added service that not all DNS hosts provide. I'm using Hover.