# Forward naked domain to www for an app on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I registered a domain example.com with GoDaddy and I have an App Engine app xyz.appspot.com

I don't want to have a Google Apps account for example.com

In GoDaddy domain management console I have 301 forwarded the naked domain to www.example.com without masking, so opening http://example.com should ideally go to http://www.example.com

In App Engine settings for xyz.appspot.com I have mapped example.com and www.example.com

Here is a screenshot of GoDaddy dns record settings:

[image]

Here's screenshot of App Engine Custom Domain Settings:

[image]

Now when I open http://example.com the app opens but the url remains http://example.com it doesn't go to http://www.example.com

I understand that in Google Apps domain management there's a setting to forward naked domain to www but I how do I achieve this without having a Google Apps account for example.com?

Answer (score 1):

Using GoDaddy "[Forwarding](https://www.godaddy.com/help/forward-a-domain-12123)" feature available in the "DNS Management" page, You will be able to setup a forward from example.com to www.example.com.

Comment: Here is an example site with the forwarding: http://subasa.info is forwarded to http://service.subasa.info

Comment: Is that site on app engine? I think this has something to do with app engine/google settings somewhere.

Comment: Not sure why, but the GoDaddy forwarding doesn't always work.  Are you using any framework like Flask or Django, which has a `before_request` feature?

Comment: I have setup GoDaddy forwarding and I am using appengine java - no framework like django/flask. Still forward doesn't happen :(

Comment: I can verify that the forwarding technique works. The Custom Domain Settings looks correct as well. I'm using Hover as the DNS provider. (Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670650/how-to-force-www-on-google-app-engine/34679266#34679266)